# Filtering CCK views by path

Tags: entities, 6

I've created a View in Drupal 6 which I am using to display a list of events. I would like to be able to filter the view by year via the path like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/events -> gives me all events
http://www.mysite.com/events/2011 -> gives me the events in 2011
http://www.mysite.com/events/2010 -> gives me the events in 2010
```

I see that you can specify arguments in the path, but I can't seem to be able to access that argument to use within the filter controls for the view. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to add a filter and use "Date: Date (node)" not "Node: Date" for a CCK date field. Then, you can choose "Select" and granularity of "Year". Once you expose the filter, you will get a drop down list to choose a year to filter by. The paths will need to be arguments, as you've found out. But, they will work separately. If you want the drop-down to only work with those specific paths, I think you have to create your own select box.

Comment: I don't see the "Date: Date (node)" option in the filters. Although I do see the "Node: Date" option. I guess I was also hoping for a little explanation as to how to tie the arguments to be used in the filter.

Comment: "Date: Date" comes from the date module. I assumed you were using that for the CCK field since you mentioned CCK. If you only have "Node: Date", then you only have the usual node create/update field, which I don't believe has these granularity functions. And, no, I don't think it is possible to directly integrate the filter and argument paths. Not that I've seen before. I'd be interested to know if that was possible.